# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-context

I keep getting this error saying "ERROR  Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by MainMenuScreen. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: [https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks"](https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks%22). Really confused don't know why am getting this error if someone can please explain or show an example it would greatly be appreciated. Many thanks for considering my request.

[Here is an image of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKglJ.png)

```
function MainMenuScreen({ navigation, route, props }) {
    const globalContext = useContext(Context)
    const { setIsLoggedIn, appSettings, domain, userObj, setUserObj, setToken, address, setAddress } = globalContext;
    const [selecedTab, setSelectedTab] = React.useState(tabs[0]);


return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['gold', '#FF7F50', '#FF7F50']} style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
            
            <FlatList 
                data={tabs}
                horizontal
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                style={{ flexGrow: 0 }}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item}-${index}`}
                renderItem={({ item: tab }) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelectedTab(tab)}>
                        <View style={[styles.pill,
                        {
                            backgroundColor: selecedTab === tab ? 'gold' : 'transparent',
                        },
                    ]}>
                            <Text style={[styles.pillText, { color: selecedTab === tab ? 'white' : 'black' }]}>{tab}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )
                }}
            />
            <FlatList
                data={popularFood}
                keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, margin: 10 }} />
                            <View>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.type}</Text>
                                <View>
                                    <AntDesign name="star" size={20} color="gold" style={{ marginRight: 10 }} />
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.rating}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}
            />
            <Text style={styles.title}>Address</Text>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{address}</Text>
        </LinearGradient>
    </View>
    );
};


Error:
 ERROR  Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by MainMenuScreen. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually happens because of any bad practice for hook implementations

**1 - Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**
Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function

> NOTE: Implement your useState hooks first at top of the function

**2 - Only Call Hooks from React Functions**
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions

**3 - Getting Error during Test**
If you get This Error when testing the component, be careful to where you set your custom hooks (replace to top of the function)

**Best Practice**
use eslint for lint your code avoid geting React Hooks Rules errors

install package with npm or yarn

```
npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks --save-dev
```

Comment: So installing this will make the error go away?

Comment: I installed the plugin but see no change.  What am I supposed to see with this plugin?  I get no indication of a problem with the react hooks in vs code but browser still shows I'm calling them wrong.